# FlinkKafkaConsumer fails to read from a LZ4 compressed topic

Tags: apache-flink, lz4

We've got several flink applications reading from Kafka topics, and they work fine. But recently we've added a new topic to the existing flink job and it started failing immediately on startup with the following root error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Exception
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$4.wrapForInput(CompressionType.java:113)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.compressedIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.streamingIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1208)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1245)
    ... 7 more
```

I found out that this topic has the **lz4** compression and guess that flink for some reason is unable to work with it. Adding lz4 dependencies directly to the app didn't work, and what's weird - it runs fine locally, but fails on the remote cluster.

The flink runtime version is **1.9.1**, and we have the same version of all other dependencies in our application:
*flink-streaming-java_2.11*, *flink-connector-kafka_2.11*, *flink-java* and *flink-clients_2.11*

Could this be happening due to flink not having a dependency to the lz4 lib inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. No version upgrade was needed, nor the additional dependencies to the application itself. What worked out for us is adding the **lz4** library jar directly to the flink libs folder in the Docker image. After that, the error with lz4 compression disappeared.